# App not redirected to Invite User Page when type on browser URL

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to access my `invite-user` route from browser `URL` by typing this route `localhost:4200/invite-user`, but app redirect me to login page

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { LoginComponent } from "src/app/components/login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "src/app/components/register/register.component";
import { InviteUserComponent } from "src/app/components/invite-user/invite-user.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "register-user", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "invite-user", component: InviteUserComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: If you remove your redirectTo route it works?, this one { path: "", redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: also to mention here that its auth routing module which inject in auth module and auth module inject in app module

Comment: my goal here is to give the access of app to user by send him This link to user

Comment: no it is no working by removing path:" "

Comment: @AhmerKhan, do you see any error in your browser console on navigation??